# How many stages can I have on a Marx generator and Cockcroft Walton multiplier?

Tags: high-voltage

The Marx generator is powered by DC. So does that mean I can add as many stages as I want? Because on a Cockcroft Walton generator people have been having to use high frequency fly back transformers that are pushing 30 kilohertz. I tried using my 60 hertz neon sign transformer on a 67 stage Cockcroft Walton generator and it didn’t work and I read it’s because I need a high frequency transformer. Now if I got my Neon sign transformer and rectified it and used a Marx generator would the Marx generator work no matter what because it’s DC current instead? What I’m trying to say is does the frequency of the transformer matter on a Marx generator like how it does on a Cockcroft Walton generator? I want it to add as many stages as I want so I can obtain millions of volts. Which generator is the best method?

Comment: Frequency doesn't matter but diodes and caps can't be too slow. A million volts will find its way where you don't want it to.

Comment: Frequency does matter